# react native mask input when using react-native-paper (material design)

Tags: react-native

I am using the InputText component from react-native-paper. How do I add input masking without having to use another library? In the image below, I want to add an input mask for the mobile number, but I don't know how to do it without using another library, and if I use another library, then I won't have the material design input style. Please help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHPiv.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use react-native-mask-input or any other mark library with react-native-paper. You can use render prop of Text Input to pass react-native-mask-input component such that

```
<TextInput
  label="Phone number"
  render={props =>
    <TextInputMask
      {...props}
      mask="+[00] [000] [000] [000]"
    />
  }
/>
```

Refer [render](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/text-input.html#render) of [TextInput](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/text-input.html)

HTH

Comment: Could you show how to do it with mask-text please? mask-input is mostly deprecated